# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in Laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, package.json

[image: Where I'm trying to use the js function]

Error I'm dealing with in the browser:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module VM87 app.js:1857

**Uncaught SyntaxError**: Unexpected identifier app.js:1857

```
@section('js')
    <script type="module" src="js/app.js">
    ...
    </script>
```

I'm trying to run a javascript function inside my dashboard view (dashboard.blade.php) in my Laravel function but when I load the page and inspect using Chrome tools I get the two errors I posted above.

I've tried various things that were "supposed" to fix it like adding type="module" to the script tag. As well as adding "type":"module" to my package.json file (https://pastebin.com/R3hf7Vh5).

What could be the cause of this error/issue and/or how do I go about debugging it?

Comment: Have you tried to rename your app.js to app.mjs? that is, using strictly the extension mjs for es6 modules?